# Consultar y Registrar un dato en PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

he estado aprendiendo poco a poco sobre sistemas web y tengo una base de datos de empleados que estoy creando, pero tengo una duda y no se como formularla de manera correcta.

Resulta que necesito a traves de un sistema de registro de datos, en el campo de nombres, yo pueda consultar el nombre de un empleado que ya esta almacenado en mi base de datos de empleados y que yo pueda ingresarlo en un input, me explico:

Tengo un archivo registro.php en el cual registro a los empleados, pero pretendo crear otro registro en el cual pueda consultar los empleados que ya registre en una casilla de texto:

```
<input type="text" name="nombres" id="nombres" placeholder="Nombres del empleado" class="form-control span8 tip" required>
```

Entonces en otra pagina de registro quiero que esa sentencia anterior al yo escribir el nombre del empleado me lo traiga a esa casilla para poder registrar otra informacion con el nombre de ese empleado, basicamente es como realizar una consulta dentro de una casilla donde al ingresar las letras del empleado me lo muestre y pueda registrarlo con otra información.

Muchas Gracias por la ayuda, si necesitan alguna parte del código con mucho gusto.

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y trata de proveer un [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que estas preguntas son en cierto sentido validas, porque a veces no se sabe ni por donde comenzar o buscar. A mi parecer tienes dos opciones.

La primera seria crear un pequeño formulario (`<form>`) en donde tengas tu `<input>` y un `<button>`. Introduces el nombre del empleado y el formulario redirige a una ruta u otro archivo php en donde hagas una consulta a tu base de datos para extraer la informacion del empleado y lo muestres en un segundo formulario. Ese segundo formulario tendria todos los inputs que necesites para mostrar la informacion y un boton para guardar/actualizar la informacion.

La segunda opcion es usar un poco de Javascript. Entiendo que, como estas empezando a aprender las tecnologias web, esto podria ser un poco mas complicado. La idea seria hacer una llamada asincrona a una ruta dentro de tu proyecto (lo mas comun en los frameworks actuales es que esta llamada llegue a un controlador), recibir la informacion relacionada a tu empleado y mostrarla en un formulario en la misma pagina, que puede aparecer/desaparecer a conveniencia usando Javascript o CSS.